# Define a two-dimensional array in a schema if values inside

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose, backend

How can I create a two-dimensional array in a schema I want to do in a schema of the user array favorite[2] [2].

```
import { Document, Schema, model } from "mongoose";
export interface IUserModel extends Document {
    favorite:string[][];
}
const UserSchema = new Schema<IUserModel>({
favorite: {
        type: [{String}]
    }})

export const UserModel = model<IUserModel>("UserModel", UserSchema, "Users"); // model name, schema class, collection name
```

But how do I put values in advance into the sample array
favorite["hello","world"]["1","2"];

Im using angular mongodb,nodejs

Answer (score 0):

```
var multi:string[][] = [["String", "String","String"],["String","String","String"]]  
console.log(multi[0][0])
```